# Trying to create a small forum by following a tutorial

Tags: php

If anyone would be able to point me in the right direction it would make my day!

I'm trying to create a forum by following this tutorial: "https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-phpmysql-powered-forum-from-scratch--net-10188".

I've created the pages with some modifications but the problem I'm getting is at the sign-in, first of all when I add the connect.php page to the sign-in page, the code doesn't echo the form, it's blank. Also when I don't use the connect page, the error messages get printed out at the start when I would like them to come after hitting submit.

I have managed to get a connection to my database and get out data with other code, but I can't seem to get this working.

```
<?php
session_start();

//signin.php
include 'forumHeader.php';
include 'connect.php';
echo '<h3>Sign in</h3>';



if(isset($_SESSION['signed_in']) && $_SESSION['signed_in'] == true)
{
    echo 'You are already signed in, you can <a href="forumSignout.php">sign out</a> if you want.</br></br>';
    echo 'Welcome, ' . $_SESSION['user_name'] . '. <a href="forumIndex.php">Proceed to the forum overview</a>.';

}

else
{




  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')
  {
      /*the form hasn't been posted yet, display it
        note that the action="" will cause the form to post to the same page it is on */
      echo '<form method="post" action="">
          Username: <input type="text" name="user_name" />
          Password: <input type="password" name="user_pass"/>
          <input type="submit" value="Sign in" />
       </form>';
  }
    /* so, the form has been posted, we'll process the data in three steps:
        1.  Check the data
        2.  Let the user refill the wrong fields (if necessary)
        3.  Varify if the data is correct and return the correct response
    */
    $errors = array(); /* declare the array for later use */


    if(!isset($_POST['user_name'])) //NOT + FALSE + POST FROM INPUT  //ISSET RETURNS FALSE WHEN CHECKING THAT HAS BEEN ASSIGNED TO NULL
    {
        $errors[] = 'The username field must not be empty.';
    }

    if(!isset($_POST['user_pass']))
    {
        $errors[] = 'The password field must not be empty.';
    }

    if(!empty($errors)) /*check for an empty array, if there are errors, they're in this array (note the ! operator)*/ //Detta betyder, om ERRORS INTE är TOM
    {
        echo 'Uh-oh.. a couple of fields are not filled in correctly..';
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach($errors as $key => $value) /* walk through the array so all the errors get displayed */
        {
            echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>'; /* this generates a nice error list */
        }
        echo '</ul>';


    }



    else
    {
        //the form has been posted without errors, so save it
        //notice the use of mysql_real_escape_string, keep everything safe!
        //also notice the sha1 function which hashes the password
        $sql = "SELECT
                    user_id,
                    user_name,
                    user_level
                FROM
                    forum_Users
                WHERE
                    user_name = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']) . "'
                AND
                    user_pass = '" . sha1($_POST['user_pass']) . "'";

        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if(!$result)
        {
            //something went wrong, display the error
            echo 'Something went wrong while signing in. Please try again later.';
            //echo mysql_error(); //debugging purposes, uncomment when needed
        }
        else
        {
            //the query was successfully executed, there are 2 possibilities
            //1. the query returned data, the user can be signed in
            //2. the query returned an empty result set, the credentials were wrong
            if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
            {
                echo 'You have supplied a wrong user/password combination. Please try again.';
            }
            else
            {
                //set the $_SESSION['signed_in'] variable to TRUE
                $_SESSION['signed_in'] = true;

                //we also put the user_id and user_name values in the $_SESSION, so we can use it at various pages
                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                    $_SESSION['user_id']    = $row['user_id'];
                    $_SESSION['user_name']  = $row['user_name'];
                    $_SESSION['user_level'] = $row['user_level'];
                }

                echo 'Welcome, ' . $_SESSION['user_name'] . '. <a href="forumIndex.php">Proceed to the forum overview</a>.';
            }
        }
    }
}


include 'forumFooter.php';
?>
```

This is pretty much the code I use for the sign-in page. The code I have at the connect.php page is:

```
<?php
//connect.php


$server = 'server';
$username   = 'user';
$password   = 'pass';
$database   = 'database';

if(!mysql_connect($server, $username, $password))
{
    exit('Error: could not establish database connection');
}
if(!mysql_select_db($database)
{
    exit('Error: could not select the database');
}

?>
```

Comment: I'd recommend using a framework like CakePHP or something smaller like Slim. Use composer for dependencies and you won't have to worry about creating stuff from scratch,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you are `echo`ing out the form you should be `else`ing into the form being processed if there is `$_POST`, atm you are going to it whether there is `$_POST` or not and trying to process empty `$_POST`s will throw errors.

Side note: set your error reporting to all using this method `error_reporting(E_ALL)`, that will let you know whats going wrong in future, it is normally set where you set `session_start()`

Comment: Thank you akaBase!! <3 That little tidbit changes EVEEERYTHING!

Comment: No problem, just note that you should turn it off once the project is published and open to the public.. don't want to be giving bad actors more info than you need to.